# How to get application details like time usage in apple mdm server?

Tags: ios, mdm

I have setup a custom mdm server for iOS. I can get the Installed application details from the enrolled iOS device.The details I can get are `'Identifier', 'Name', 'BundleSize', 'Version', 'ShortVersion', 'DynamicSize'`
But I need to get the time usage of particular app. Please let me know if it is possible or not, if so how can I do that and also if any work around is possible. Thank you.

Comment: It seems as not possible. See here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191102/is-it-possible-to-track-installed-apps-usage-on-ios-devices-using-mdm-profiles

Comment: Thank you for your response, so I am clear that it is not possible through mdm. But they have said something about side loading apps. So we can do the monitoring on client side itself?

Comment: "they have said" - I don't understand who said that...

Comment: The answer in the thread you have posted, `The only way I can think of would be to side-load (using an Enterprise Distribution certificate/profile) an app that uses private APIs to monitor such activity and report back. Not recommended and against the Developer Program T&Cs I believe...`

Comment: I don't know, you can ask there. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @zvi, I will ask there.